# SQL - Inserting data where values are an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I want to be able to add an array of strings to a table so that each string is a new row (in PHP).

This is it in psuedo-code:

```
$Array = "10000,10001,10002,10003";
$Data = "ImportantData";
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO MyTable(`id`,`data`) VALUES($Array, $Data)");
```

So that a previously empty table would look like:

```
id      | data      
------------------------
10000   | ImportantData
10001   | ImportantData
10002   | ImportantData
10003   | ImportantData
```

In an update script, with those rows already established, I could just say:

```
mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE MyTable SET data = $Data WHERE `id` IN($Array));
```

However I want it to create rows, not just update old ones.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a foreach loop on $Array, and insert the data.  I assume you want to update it if it exists as it makes little sense to create a new record with the same PK, so use the following (assumes you are using PHP PDO

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id,data) VALUES (:id,:data) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data=:data;
```

Comment: A foreach loop would mean multiple queries. Since I was able to do it with just one with the update, I was hoping there was a similar method  with insert.

Comment: You could, but my concern about multiple PKs still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE INTO`:

```
REPLACE INTO table SET id = 10001, data = 'new important data';
```

MySQL documentation:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to put the array in there though, since I'm not explicitly telling it to set id = 10001. I want it to set data = 'ImportantData' for every unique ID in the $Array, in one query.